# Lambda expression "cannot bind'

Tags: c++, lambda

So basically I am trying to get the heaviest animal on the farm, using lambdas. But I am stuck and I don't really get how to fix this.

The problem occurs in when calling the method `killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm();` and printing this in.
(see `main.cpp`)

I have an Animal class

animal.h

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Animal
  {
  public:
    Animal(std::string aType, const char & anSex, float aWeight);

    std::string getType() const {return type;}
    char getSex() const {return sex;};
    float getWeight() const {return weight;};
    void setWeight(float value) {weight = value;};

    void feed(int amount);
    Animal breed(Animal &aFather);

  private:
    const std::string type;
    const char sex;
    float weight;
  };

std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, Animal *an);

#endif // ANIMAL_H
```

animal.cpp

```
#include "animal.h"
#include "farm.h"

Animal::Animal(std::string aType, const char &aSex, float aWeight) :
  type{aType}, sex{aSex}, weight{aWeight}
  {
  }

void Animal::feed(int amount)
  {
  if (type == "sheep")
    weight += amount * 0.02f;
  else
    if (type == "cow")
      weight += amount * 0.05f;
  }

Animal Animal::breed(Animal &aFather)
  {
  float startWeight = (type == "cow") ? 35.0f : 6.5f;
  if (aFather.getType() == type && aFather.getSex() == 'M')
  return Animal(type, 'F', startWeight);
  }
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, Animal *an)
  {
  std::string animal = an->getType();
  animal += "(";
  animal += an->getSex();
  animal +=  ")";
  os << animal <<  ", current weight = " << an->getWeight() << std::endl;
  return os;
  }
```

And a farm class

farm.h

```
#ifndef FARM_H
#define FARM_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "animal.h"

class Farm
  {
  public:
    Farm(std::string farmName);

    std::string getName() const {return name;};

    void addAnimal(Animal &newAnimal);
    Animal killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm();

  private:
    const std::string name;
    std::vector<Animal> animals;

  };

#endif // FARM_H
```

Farm.cpp

```
#include "farm.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>



Farm::Farm(std::string farmName):name{farmName}
  {

  }

void Farm::addAnimal(Animal &newAnimal)
  {
  animals.push_back(newAnimal);
  }


Animal Farm::killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm()
  {
  std::max_element(animals.begin(), animals.end(), [] (Animal first, Animal second)
  {
    return first.getWeight() < second.getWeight();
    });

  }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "farm.h"
#include <memory>

int main()
  {
  Farm meuhBoeh("Tradition in Technology");
  Animal * eva = new Animal("sheep", 'F', 35.2f);
  Animal * adam = new Animal("sheep", 'M', 45.6f);
  Animal * bella = new Animal("cow", 'F', 256.3f);
  Animal * taurus = new Animal("cow", 'F', 343.8f);
  meuhBoeh.addAnimal(*eva);
  meuhBoeh.addAnimal(*adam);
  meuhBoeh.addAnimal(*bella);
  meuhBoeh.addAnimal(*taurus);

  std::cout << "Animal slaughtered = " << meuhBoeh.killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm() << std::endl;

  }
```

I get following error:

```
/main.cpp:17: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
   std::cout << "Animal slaughtered = " << meuhBoeh.killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm() << std::endl;
             ^
```

I can't seem to be able to find how to fix this..

EDIT (solution)

Animal.h

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os,const Animal &an);
```

Animal.cpp

Updated operator

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & os, const Animal &an)
  {
  std::string animal = an.getType();
  animal += "(";
  animal += an.getSex();
  animal +=  ")";
  os << animal <<  ", current weight = " << an.getWeight() << std::endl;
  return os;
  }
```

Main.cpp

```
 std::cout << "Animal slaughtered = " << meuhBoeh.killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm() << std::endl;
```

Farm.cpp

(Tried using (Animal first, Animal second) also, but same error)

```
Animal Farm::killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm()
  {
  std::max_element(animals.begin(), animals.end(), [] (Animal &first, Animal &second)
  {
    return first.getWeight() < second.getWeight();
    });

  }
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:33: error: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Animal)'
```

Comment: The error points to "<<". Why would you think the lambda is the culprit?

Comment: Well it only throwed an error when trying to call the lambda function, that's why I though this was the problem. I still didn't get to fix the problem though, even though my overload now takes a reference of Animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer is **NOT** complete since it solves the first two drafts of
>   the question but failed to solve the final draft..

`killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm` returns an `Animal` not a `string` or any overloads of the operator `<<`.
I think you want something like;

```
auto killed=meuhBoeh.killHeaviestAnimalOnFarm();
std::cout << "Animal slaughtered = " << killed.name << std::endl;
```

**After the question edited:**

your `overload` take a `pointer` of `Animal` but you are trying to pass an `object` so either edit the overloading to be just `Animal` or better `Animal const&` rather than `Animal*` or pass the reference of the result to the `std::cout`. Of course, the first solution is preferable IMO.

Comment: I forgot to put  something, one sec

Comment: I have overloaded the operator in Animal.cpp

Comment: I did :) see Animal.cpp and Animal.h

Comment: it take pointer of an animal and you are trying to pass an object

Comment: Could I change the operator to have "Animal &an" instead of "Animal *an"? (Obv change the -> to '.'), that still doesn't work though

Comment: it should work,, show us the final code you got and the error message please

Comment: put the declaration of << inside the class with the friend keyword before it. I have just googled your problem and that the solution I got.. try it i if did not work IDK..